# Maybe a bug in temporal reasoning on drools?

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I want to test a scenario with temporal reasoning on drools. I have a Message class with timestamp field. when each event of this class received by drools, inserted into working memory and called fireAllRules(). in every firing I want to print timestamp of paired message ml and mo, that is ml after[0s,160s] mo. when I write my rule like below every things is Ok.

```
rule "Rule 1"
when
    ml: Message()
    mo: Message(ml after[0s,160s] this)
then
    System.out.println("ml:"+new Date(ml.timestamp));
    System.out.println("mo:"+new Date(mo.timestamp));
end
```

output:

```
Message received{"timestamp":"Feb  8 19:39:45", ... }
ml:Sun Feb 08 19:39:45 IRST 1970
mo:Sun Feb 08 19:39:45 IRST 1970
Message received{"timestamp":"Feb  8 19:40:04", ... }
ml:Sun Feb 08 19:40:04 IRST 1970
mo:Sun Feb 08 19:39:45 IRST 1970
ml:Sun Feb 08 19:40:04 IRST 1970
mo:Sun Feb 08 19:40:04 IRST 1970
Message received{"timestamp":"Feb  8 19:40:15", ... }
ml:Sun Feb 08 19:40:15 IRST 1970
mo:Sun Feb 08 19:40:04 IRST 1970
ml:Sun Feb 08 19:40:15 IRST 1970
mo:Sun Feb 08 19:39:45 IRST 1970
ml:Sun Feb 08 19:40:15 IRST 1970
mo:Sun Feb 08 19:40:15 IRST 1970
```

But when I rewrite rule in this form the output is not good.

```
rule "Rule 1"
when
    ml: Message()
    mo: Message(this before[0s,160s] ml)
then
    System.out.println("ml:"+new Date(ml.timestamp));
    System.out.println("mo:"+new Date(mo.timestamp));
end
```

output:

```
Message received{"timestamp":"Feb  8 19:41:40", ... }
ml:Sun Feb 08 19:41:40 IRST 1970
mo:Sun Feb 08 19:41:40 IRST 1970
Message received{"timestamp":"Feb  8 19:41:57", ... }
ml:Sun Feb 08 19:41:57 IRST 1970
mo:Sun Feb 08 19:41:57 IRST 1970
Message received{"timestamp":"Feb  8 19:42:02", ... }
ml:Sun Feb 08 19:42:02 IRST 1970
mo:Sun Feb 08 19:42:02 IRST 1970
```

Why in second form the output is not good? this problem observed when I used two parameters for temporal operators and "this" is the first operand.
Is "this before[0s,160s] ml" equals to "ml after[0s,160s] this"?
The second form is a bug?

Comment: Please provide a complete example reproducing the "bug": Java code for Message and for creating the session and inserting facts in addition to your rules.

Comment: It is so clear and It is not necessary to provide java code. there is a simple message class with a timestamp field and a STREAM session with realtime clock. you can easily write this example and and test it.

Comment: I have something quite similar, and it does not reproduce the effect you have described. - I have enough experience with claims such as yours, and I'm not going to waste any more time unless you provide the goods, in full, including the Drools version.